# How to get a snapshot of an MJPEG stream in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mjpeg

I'm having an mjpeg stream of devices streaming from a nodeJS server. The server allows just one stream request for a device for security reasons and hence I cannot re-paint the stream on a canvas and neither can I use canvas instead of img tag for displaying the stream. Is there any other way by which I can get a screenshot directly from the stream in the client?

Comment: Or if there is a way by which I can use the image data loaded from the browser using JS...

Answer (score 0):

Check getImageData() if you are using canvas: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: I cannot use canvas as I described in the question. Is there any other way??